# What is the best wiring for NEMA 14-50 receptacle in a 240V country?

Tags: wiring, 240v

I moved from US and I would like to install a NEMA 14-50 in my home outside US for my EV car. I am outside the US and electricity here is 240 volts. I wonder if I can wire it in this form and do I need to wire an additional neutral wire.

I was planning to connect the X port to live wire and Y port to neutral wire and G for earth. Do I need to an additional neutral wire for N port.

[image: Proposed wiring to plug]

Comment: Why not install a wall mount Type 2 outlet? Or at least replace your charging cable with one that has your national socket type?

Comment: I really don't know how that's meant to work in Europe [though we haven't been told precisely where 'outside US']. Doesn't the US need 3-phase for 240v? EU has 240v per phase, 415v on 3-phase. Not sure how those would marry up in practise.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- no, US residential power is mostly 120/240V *split phase* -- 240V line-to-line, with neutral connected to the center tap of that

Comment: Replacing my charging cable is next step if this is not going to work. I may have to buy a whole new charger which is expensive. By my proposal and using single phase, I will get 240V across the X/Y ports, similar to US!

Comment: It may be a matter of just a cable. What charger/cable/etc. are you using? Specific make/model would help a lot. (Ignoring the technical "charger is really part of the car" issue - I'm referring to whatever "thing" is between the car and the wall.)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - this says to me the OP's proposed wiring scheme will then just go *bang* somewhere important.

Comment: @Tetsujin No. Bad things are more likely to happen in the other direction (connecting rest-of-world 240V L/N equipment to US power). Such devices might have their “neutral” input terminal connected to metal pieces that users might be able to touch (light bulb base shell, etc). This is pretty safe if N is actually connected to neutral (0V). Bring it to the US where both sides of a 240V feed are 120V from ground, that’s dangerous.

Comment: All bets are off, of course, if the device actually requires both 240V and 120V - there’s no way to just wire that up in the rest of the world - you need a transformer.

Comment: What country are you located in? Electric codes vary, but in Europe what you propose would *probably* be illegal.

Answer (score 2):

You won't need to replace your EVSE.

However you should not install a NEMA 14-50 that way.  You have the wiring correct, but that socket promises something that isn't there - neutral at the midpoint and 120v to either hot wire.  That midpoint neutral is extremely important; without it, 120V loads will see excessive voltage, and potentially burn!

If you must use a North American socket type, then use NEMA 6-50.  This is correct for 240V between the hots, no neutral, and ground.

*Then why the bleep do EVSE's all use 14-50 and not 6-50?  Darned if I know.   I think the idea was that EV owners tend to be richer and more likely to have an existing 14-50 to power an RV.   And even worse, thousands of new North American EVSE installations are done with /2 wire and 14-50, leaving the neutral unconnected... so many RVs will plug into those and suffer thousands of dollars of damage to their microwaves and HVAC systems because of that foolishness. (Most RV HVAC is 120V equipment so it will work on TT30 connections; lack of neutral will be deadly to that equipment).  It is a huge blunder for EVSE manufacturers to recommend the 14-50*.

The correct answer is to hack off the 14-50 *on all EVSEs, everywhere*, and put 6-50 on them instead.

Keep in mind that you will not be able to obtain a 50A breaker in European markets.  You would be much, much better off installing the EVSE using the gold-standard methods domestic to that country, including the derate. For instance North America requires an EVSE to have 125% derate, so for a 40A-actual charge rate, a 50A circuit is required.  You should follow your domestic rules in that country.

Answer (score 1):

The neutral pin of this type of outlet in the US allows the connected device to obtain 120V between it and either of the other hot conductors.

**If your charger requires this** you should buy a new charger designed for your location.  Using your existing one won't be practical or economical. It's not just wiring up this outlet, it's providing it with US-style split phase 120/240V power.  Sure that's possible, but put the money into a new charger that will enhance the value of your home rather than loading up your garage with a home-brewed electrical supply.

**If your charger does not require a 120V capability**, you would be better off installing an outlet that is standard for your location and replacing the *plug* on your existing charger to match it.  Alternately look at whether your charger and your local standards permit hard wiring, and if so ... do that.  Skip the plug and socket.

Comment: Do ***not*** replace the plug on electrical charging cables. They're not just a plug; they commonly include a temperature sensor to stop charging in case of high plug temperatures.

Comment: Agreed if it's not just a plug don't replace it with a plug.  Another argument for hard wiring if that's possible.